# Vertical Alignment of Digits with MinionPro

Tags: vertical-alignment, minionpro

First of all, thanks for your great help and support - I have been able to find answers to pretty much all my latex questions on here. For this one, however, I could not find a solution.

I am currently facing problems with the vertical placement of numerical digits when using the MinionPro Font. As can be seen from the minimum working example and attached image below, latex correctly aligns the first digit with the text. However, some of the subsequent digits are set lower.

I feel like it interrupts readability, especially on pages with lots of digits, the TOC and headers.

How can I force latex to vertically align all digits the same way?

Thanks a lot in advance!

[image: Example image showing the vertical alignment for digits in the mwe]

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt,openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage{MinionPro}

\begin{document} 

This tests vertical digit placement as regular text: 1.99 and in math context: $1.8$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: These are called OldStyle or LowerCase figures, and are set lower by design. Depending on the intention of the numbers it is nice to use these in the main text since they actually follow the natural flow of the text better. In math mode, however, it is better to use Lining or UpperCase figures. It depends on the font whether it provides such characters or not, but I'd think Minion Pro should provide them. However, since I don't have Minion Pro to play around with, and I don't know exactly what your MinionPro package definition does I can't help you get the Lining figures.

Comment: Thanks @hugovdberg, lining was the keyword I needed. I was able to fix it with

'\usepackage[textlf]{MinionPro}
\usepackage[textlf]{MyriadPro}'

Comment: It is fine to answer your own question, that way it doesn't linger around as an unanswered question.

Comment: I certainly will, as soon as I am allowed to (need to wait 8 hours first as I have never posted before). Cheers.

Comment: I think you may want `lf` option instead. I use `mathlf` since I only want lining figures in math mode. By the way, the standard way of dealing with this kind of questions is first [reading the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/minionpro/MinionPro.pdf). In that case there is a section named *Figure selection*.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer towards the documentation. I had searched it for selected keywords (for instance 'digits' or 'numbers' if I remember correctly), but this did not give any results. Good to know it is in the 'Figure' section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minion Pro offers 4 kinds of digits, according to the combination of Lining/Oldstyle and Tabular/Proportional features you choose. Tabular digits (or Monospaced) have all the same character width, which makes them suitable for array-like environment. Here is a simple demonstration:

```
        \documentclass{article}
        \usepackage{fontspec} 
        \setmainfont{Minion Pro}
        \usepackage{array, makecell}
        \newcommand*\nml{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Monospaced,Lining}}}%
        \newcommand*\nmo{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Monospaced,OldStyle}}}%
        \newcommand*\npl{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Proportional,Lining}}}%
        \newcommand*\npo{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}}}%


        \begin{document}

       \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\nml}c| >{\nmo}c|@{\quad}|>{\npl}c |>{\npo}c|}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Tabular\quad} &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Proportional}\\
        \hline
        \thead{Lining} & \thead{OldStyle} & \thead{Lining} & \thead{OldStyle}\\
        \hline
       12345 & 12345  & 12345 & 12345  \\
        67890& 67890 & 67890& 67890 \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \end{center}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

As far as I know, most *Pro* Opentype fonts have these 4 kinds of figures.

To take full advantage of opentype features, you might consider compiling with XeLaTeX ot LuaLaTeX, using (as in the example) the `fontspec` package only for text (`nomath` option) and  the `MinionPro` package for maths (option `onlymath`)

Comment: I don't know what “opentype features” do you refer to, but remember that `MinionPro` package takes care of many many things and has lots of options for getting the desired result.

Comment: It refers to things like special ligatures (c-t, s-t, s-p), letterspacing, contextual variants, and so on. For instance, if you want an 18th-century looking text, it will be able to use the old style "s", that looks like an f, except if it's at the end of word.  `MinionPro`, as far as I know, cannot handle this, but `fontspec`can.

Comment: True, I was just trying to point out that `MinionPro` has many options and many many features (like Swash, `footnotefigures`, etc.) which could be enough for many people.

Comment: You preach to the choir: before Xe/LuaLaTeX, I've been using it for more than 10 years.

Comment: Usually I use MinionPro + Mnsymbol for maths and Minion Pro or Sabon Next LT Pro for text (with XeLaTeX). But did you give a try at `mathabx` ? `abx` is an option for the calligraphic math font in MinionPro (it even has lowercase calligraphic letters), but it has quite an impressive set of symbols, including some that don't exist in amsfonts nor in amssymb.It is dark enough to match MinionPro.

Comment: @Manuel `MinionPro` has an `onlytext` option which prevents its use in maths. I assume you want something different?

Comment: @Manuel See my attempt at satisfying some of your desiderata...